# Script not working in wordpress admin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datatable

I have a code in which I want to display tables with datatables script.

```
function viewBooks_admin(){

?>
<div class="wrap">
<h4>Books List</h4>

<table id="widefat" class="widefat">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Book Description</th>
            <th>Author Name</th>
            <th>Book Price</th>
            <th>Book Image</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Book Description</th>
            <th>Author Name</th>
            <th>Book Price</th>
            <th>Book Image</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            global $wpdb;
            $mytestdrafts=$wpdb->get_results(
                "
                SELECT *
                from ".$wpdb->prefix."books
                "
            );
        ?>
        <?php
            foreach($mytestdrafts as $mytestdraft)
            {
        ?>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                        echo"<td>".$mytestdraft->bookName."</td>";
                        echo"<td>".$mytestdraft->bookDescription."</td>";
                        echo"<td>".$mytestdraft->authourName."</td>";
                        echo"<td>".$mytestdraft->bookPrice."</td>";
                        echo"<td><img src='".$mytestdraft->imageURL."' width='80' height='80'></td>";
                        //echo "<td><a class='btn button-danger' href=''>"
                    ?>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br><br>

</div>
<?php

}
```

Add adding this css and javascript

```
function your_css_and_js() {

        //register style 
        wp_register_style('datatable_css', plugins_url('css/jquery.dataTables.css',__FILE__ ));
        wp_enqueue_style('datatable_css');

        ////register scripts
        wp_register_script( 'jquery-dataTables', plugins_url('js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',__FILE__ ), array('jquery'), true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-dataTables');

        wp_register_script( 'custom', plugins_url('js/custom.js',__FILE__ ), array('jquery'), true);
        wp_enqueue_script('custom');

    }

    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts','your_css_and_js');
```

**Custom.js file**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log('dfdfd');
    $("#widefat").dataTable();
 })
```

The page is loading scripts but datatables are not visible . Don't know why. 
Followed this tutorial for datatables though working file in html https://www.bmthrive.com/datatables-jquery-plugin/

Comment: can you reproduce the issue? somewhere?

Comment: its in wordpress plugin . ... How can i show you? .should I share my code?

Comment: yes please, if you can.

Comment: I guess you will have to add data table classes to your table, td and tr elements, this should fix the issue i guess. here classes is css class.

Comment: full code is here

Comment: see my code . i have added class to table already and see tutorial also just table class is needed

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: no error in console

Comment: can you provide working link somewhere where I can see what's happening, then only i can help. thanks

Comment: Try `jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {});`. As a sidenote, you're enqueing your styles/scripts all over the admin, it should be only on your custom page.

Comment: i later found that it is a error in datable jquery.....